# Python - hashlib won't "pick up" the files in a routine

Tags: python, hashlib

I'm using the hashlib func in a script I'm writing, and I can't get it to take the files I'm pointing it towards - its only returning the hash of a 0kb file `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`.

I'm calling it like so: `fHash=md5Checksum(f)` where `f` is a full path string of a file.

The md5Checksum func is a lift from here: http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/02/md5-hash-of-file-in-python/ and I've tested the 2nd example directly with an explicitly typed path to a file and it returns the correct hash.

I am also using the `os.path.getsize` method in the same way (`fSize=os.path.getsize(f)`) and that is picking the file up correctly.

When I dump the contents of the `f` string in my code, and compare it to the explicitly typed path, I notice it lacks `'` markers around the string:

`/home/.../(500) Days of Summer[2009]/11 - Regina Spektor - Hero.mp3` from a 'print f'

and from the explicitly typed path:

`print 'The MD5 checksum of text.txt is', md5Checksum('/home/.../deduper/test.txt')` (which works)

If I manually add `'` markers to the path the code falls over:

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'/home/.../(500) Days of Summer[2009]/11 - Regina Spektor - Hero.mp3'"`

This makes me suspect I'm not passing the path correctly. I'm on a ubuntu box if that matters.

***EDIT***

I'm a buffoon. I've been stuck on this for a few days, and its only through posting it on here and checking the indentations I've noticed I've messed one of them up on the md5Checker method along the way... I've fixed it, and this totally works. Thank you all for making me check.... (for the record, I had the `m.update(data)` line inline with the break. Thats not going to work now is it.... :s

```
def md5Checksum(filePath):
 fh = open(filePath, 'rb')
 m = hashlib.md5()
 # print "File being hashed: " + filePath
 while True:
  data = fh.read(8192)
  if not data:
   break
  m.update(data)
 return m.hexdigest()
```

Comment: I don't think you have to add the `'` to the file path. But indeed it seems that you have some problem with the file name. Could you post your `md5Checksum` method ?

Comment: `print ()`, displays the contents of a string, so it wouldn't show the single/double quotes that denote a *string literal* in python (they're not part of the string).

Comment: Does `print open(...).read()` work?

Comment: I've fixed it. I was a dummy. I'm not sure if I should leave it here for posterity or delete the question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had somehow got the indentation misalign, not enough to cause it to fall over and give me an error, but enough for it to not work. Answer is posted in the original question.